# Prevent VLC from looping playlist

Tags: windows, video, vlc-media-player, playlists

I'm trying to prevent VLC from looping back to the beginning of a playlist when I hit *"next video"*. Is there a way to disable it from playing the first video in a playlist if you click "next video in playlist" while the last video in the playlist is currently playing?

Essentially I need this functionality:

- *"next video"* moves to the next video in the playlist for all videos except the last video in the playlist.
- if *"next video"* is pressed while the last video is currently playing, nothing happens.

Comment: I haven't looked into VLC settings but is it specific to some version or have you looked at playback settings ?

Comment: I've looked at all the settings, both basic and advanced before I asked the question. I was hoping there was some functionality I could implement beyond what was in those checkboxes somehow, or that maybe I'd overlooked something.

Answer (score 5):

At the bottom of the player where the controls are you'll see 9 control buttons (play, fast reverse, stop, fast forward, etc.). The 8th control button (2 opposite facing arrows) is the loop control toggle. First click is "loop all", second click is "loop 1", third click is "no loop"

Comment: This does not achieve the functionality I was looking for. Even with "no loop" selected, pressing "next video" still returns to the first video in the playlist when the last video in the playlist is playing. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For mac this setting can be found in the menu bar, under Playback.
Just select the option you prefer, or disable by selecting the active option.
[here is a screenshot of the menu dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp45w.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have the latest version (albeit on a Mac), browsed through the settings, both basic and advanced, and there seems to be no support for the function you want. Although, of course I might have just failed to find it or it may be a totally different story on windows.

Comment: Yeah, I browsed through all the settings as well, I was hoping I'd overlooked something or that there was some wizardly scripting I could implement.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Windows or Mac...

In the Toolbar, next to Shuffle...

[image]

[image]

Comment: This does not achieve the functionality I'm after, I'm not sure if you tested or not. Even with loop off, pressing "next video" still returns to the first video in the playlist when the last video in the playlist is playing.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck "Repeat All" from the "Playback" drop-down menu.

Comment: This does not achieve the functionality I was looking for. Even with "repeat all" unselected, pressing "next video" still returns to the first video in the playlist when the last video in the playlist is playing. Thanks anyway.